# How to Omit property in type by property type

Tags: typescript

i have a type with some properties typed string, number, etc..., and i want to omit some properties who's type isn't string.

the `Omit<T, U>` generic just omit by property name, but not property type.

for example:

```
class Person {
  name: string;
  age: number;
  eat(food: Food): void;
  walk(miles: number): void;
  read(book: Book): void;
}

// =>

type PersonAbility = PickAbility<Person>;

// how can i write a PickAbility<T> generic, results:

type PersonAbility = {
  eat(food: Food): void;
  walk(miles: number): void;
  read(book: Book): void;
}
```

as the code above.

and i have try this:

```
type PersonAbility = {
  [K in keyof Person]: Person[K] extends (payload: {}) => Promise<{}> ? Person[K] : never
};

// it results:

type PersonAbility = {
  name: never;
  age: never;
  eat: (food: Food) => void;
  walk: (miles: number) => void;
  read: (book: Book) => void;
}
```

the codes above set the property not needed to `never`, but not remove it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution here is to get the union of keys corresponding to the property values you want, and then `Pick` those.  Here's one way to do it:

```
type KeysMatching<T, V> = {
  [K in keyof T]-?: T[K] extends V ? K : never
}[keyof T];
```

`KeysMatching<T, V>` uses a [mapped](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types), [conditional](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#conditional-types), and [lookup](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html#keyof-and-lookup-types) type to find the keys of type `T` whose property values are assignable to type `V`.

Then we can make `PickMatching<T, V>` which just `Pick`s those values:

```
type PickMatching<T, V> = Pick<T, KeysMatching<T, V>>;
```

And `PickAbility<T>` will just use `PickMatching` on `Function`-valued properties (your example code uses `(payload: {}) => Promise<{}>` but none of your `Person` methods match that):

```
type PickAbility<T> = PickMatching<T, Function>;
```

Let's test it:

```
type PersonAbility = PickAbility<Person>;
/*
type PersonAbility = {
    eat: (food: Food) => void;
    walk: (miles: number) => void;
    read: (book: Book) => void;
}
*/
```

Looks good.  Hope that help; good luck!

[Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/PTAEBUE8AcFNQCawGYEsB2qAuqD26BnUZXAJ1AEcBXWAnfAKAy1lOQEMBjeAMV1wSgA3g1Ch07ALawAXKDqkMAcwDco0J3YAbMqlpz0VSQCNWagL5N0LNl3gAhfgGth6nFi2z5WRelXr2KiwACzI5BWULKxsOblAABVYCfFcxCWlwn0iApS9DEzN1WHYsAAoSATk+AQBKOQA3XFQENTEAd20nUslUTwIDI1NSOtBG5tbQUmKEUuNnOUdcJxGxloZLBgYQUABlXC0gvHRNrBh4AGlYSAIAWRLOYOUAHnAAGlAANQA+UABeVNAAG1zqAMKAnFdcMgIABdAC0AH45OBgTDQLAAB4sdAIIgfUAI0AggyweqsdaAiGQKGwtQMU5wBKoThOO5YB7PN6fH7-eLMpwvd6Xa5sjl+QXcr50hnwPksgCCxl62EgLx5TJZose4q5PCo6E49HQUpOZwSSXwiuVpz+GqcVq0KqeiVIyWNamAACp6WaXW6HSrbSIxGJilg5OV+AgqlGan8fqsJu1OhGen0BgVhvHRk01iHJtMI3MlgtnHHfgnc1FPcAGEA)