# There is a way to skip certain types

Tags: typescript

I have a type

```
type Person = { id: string; name: boolean; su:number }
```

Using Omit you can skip certain properties.

```
type Sedra = Omit<Person, "su"|"id">;
// {name: boolean;}
```

There is a way in typescript to skip certain types.

example

```
 type Sedra = OmitType<Person, boolean|number >;
    // {id: string;}
```

**There is an OmitType type ?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Omit property in type by property type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57044386/how-to-omit-property-in-type-by-property-type/57044690)

Answer (score 2):

You can make one:

```
type KeysMatching<T, V> = {
  [K in keyof T]-?: T[K] extends V ? K : never
}[keyof T];

type OmitType<T, V> = Omit<T, KeysMatching<T, V>>;
```

This works by using a [mapped](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types) and [conditional](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#conditional-types) type to filter the keys of `T` that match a value `V`, and then using `Omit` on that.  (It's not clear what you want to see happen if `T` has some optional properties or index signatures, but since you didn't ask, I just made some assumptions).

You can verify that it works:

```
type Sedra = OmitType<Person, boolean | number | undefined>;
/* type Sedra = {
    id: string;
}  */
```

Hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?jsx=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAChBOBnA9gOygXigbygSwBMAuKRYePVAcwG4pUBDAWwhICNlkAbCB1OxAFcSqQUzYIoAXxoAoWaEhQA0hBCIAsg2ABjABaUqAHgAqAGigA1AHyYcsqFADay-OgDWa5ADMoJgLoAtAD8JCYu-lAQAB7AEKgEiFZQwSpQIhAAbgiyUk6eID5+-nIK4NAA8kx4wCblphY2dlU1DSpqmtr6hm021qWK0ADKEATwDM3VtfVwSGgWHNy86AA+9GIS8FBrggkQ3pSj-bIA9ABUUINQI2MTWNgOjvjEpOSGclKOZyeyQA)