# Typescript Omit or Exclude by type of property

Tags: typescript

I want to make a new type that only has some of the properties of a parent type based on the type of those properties.

For example I want a Post type that only includes strings.

```js
type Post = {
  id: string;
  title: string;
  numberOfLikes: number;
  ...
}

// This doesn't work
type PostStringsOnly = Extract<Post, string>

const postOnlyWithStringKeys: PostStringsOnly = {
  id: "123",
  title: "The best post!"
}
```

I want to use this for a Generic type that I don't know all of the keys of up front. So specifically Omitting "numberOfLikes" will not work. It needs to be by type.

Comment: Here's the solution from the [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57044386/how-to-omit-property-in-type-by-property-type) applied to your code: https://tsplay.dev/mLRM4w (or [all in one](https://tsplay.dev/wO8bzN).) The key (no pun) is going indirectly via the keys, by figuring out the keys of the string-typed properties, then using `Pick`.

Comment: maybe use this: https://github.com/krzkaczor/ts-essentials#pickproperties

Comment: @TmTron and t-j-crowder thank you both! Both of these worked perfectly 

Answer (score -2):

```
type Post = {
  id: string;
  title: string;
  numberOfLikes: number
}

type PostStringsOnly = Omit<Post, 'numberOfLikes'>

const postOnlyWithStringKeys: PostStringsOnly = {
  id: "123",
  title: "The best post!"
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this - I should have specified that I don't want to list the keys specifically!  I will update the question to be more clear